# Change coordinate of numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I wonder if there is an elegant way to customize another coordinate system for numpy array? The reason I hope to change the coordinate system is I hope to avoid any potential error in my simulation process.

For example, if I want an object move upwards, from `(2,2)` to `(2,3)` in a normal coordinate. I have to write like from `[2,2]` to `[1,2]` in a numpy array. I am very concerned that I will make some errors in a large simulation process.

So I want to know what is the most elegant way so that I can think of the numpy array as a normal coordinate system?  For example, for a numpy array `A` with the shape of `(500,500)`, I want `A(2,2)` actually points to `A[498, 2]`. And I can easily describe an upward movement using `A(2,2)` to `A(2, 20)`, which equivalent to numpy array from `A[498, 2]` to `A[480, 2]`

Comment: If you don't know it already, xarray might be of interest to you.  [xarray is like numpy with labeled axes and a coordinate system](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/getting-started-guide/quick-overview.html#create-a-dataarray).

Answer (score 0):

You can continue using the same indices, but create a slice that reverses the original array. Since both arrays refer to the same memory, changes to one will be reflected in the other. Modify data in the original array, and visualize it using the reversed array:

```
act_data = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=int)
view_data = act_data[::-1, :]

act_data[0, 0] = 1
print(view_data)
for i in range(1, 5):
    act_data[i-1, i-1] = 0
    act_data[i, i] = 1
    print(view_data)
```

And you can see the `1` move from the bottom-left to the top-right:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]]

[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]

[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]

[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]

[[0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```